# Requested value '{MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}' was not found

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

Good Night,

i got an error when i tried to connect to the mysql database using c#. i am using mysql odbc 3.51 64 bit driver. here is my connection string

```
public static string konek = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=d_undangan;User=root;Password=;Option=3;";
```

Comment: What is the platform target of your app? It is x86 or AnyCPU? I suppose you are running your code on a 64bit system right?

Comment: What was the error... do you mean an exception was raised? Which exception? Can you include the exact Exception.ToString() output?

Comment: my platform target is x86. my system is using 64 bit operating system

Comment: System.ArgumentException : {"Requested value '{MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}' was not found."}

Comment: Did you configure the ODBC Driver according to?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-odbc-configuration.html